# Declare and Initialize Typescript class members

Tags: typescript

My class looks like this...

```
class MyClass {
    c: number;
    avg: number;
    diam: number;

    constructor(a: number, b: number) {
        this.c = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
        this.avg = (a + b) / 2;
        this.diam = Math.abs(b - a);
    }
}
```

... but actually has more members that need declaring and initialising **from the constructor arguments**.   I want to avoid the boilerplate of declaring the members outside the constructor and inside the constructor.   Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, TypeScript supports something like that:

```js
class MyClass {
    c: number = Math.sqrt(this.a * this.a + this.b * this.b);
    avg: number = (this.a + this.b) / 2;
    diam: number = Math.abs(this.b - this.a);

    constructor(public a: number, private readonly b: number) {
    }
}
```

That'll create a public field `a` and a private read-only field `b`. These are created before the initializers for the regular fields are executed, thus you can access those too.

Comment: I don't want members for the constructor arguments.  I want members that have different names from the arguments, and which are calculated from the arguments.

Comment: @AdamGawne-Cain I've updated my example where field initializes access constructor-parameters-turned-fields. Don't think you can access the constructor parameters if you don't mark them as fields, though. That's what the constructor is meant to be used for, to be fair.

Comment: Thanks for your update @Kelvin.  Your updated answer is useful for me as I knew about converting arguments to fields, but I didn't know you could use existing fields in field initialise expressions outside the constructor.   In practice I want (most of) the arguments as fields anyway.   However, I was hoping there was some way to make the constructor body definitive in declaring fields if the compiler could determine each field was defined exactly once, a bit like Java's rule for setting the value of "final" members in constructors.

Comment: @AdamGawne-Cain If it answers your question well enough, don't forget to mark the answer as the solution

Comment: I've upvoted you as your answer is useful (thanks!).  If someone knows a way to declare and initialise all fields together in one place then I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do smth like that:

```js
interface MathData {
    c: number;
    avg: number;
    diam: number;
}

const builder = (a: number, b: number):MathData => ({
    c: Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b),
    avg: (a + b) / 2,
    diam: Math.abs(b - a),
})


class MyClass {
    constructor(a: number, b: number) {
        Object.assign(this, builder(a, b));

    }
    calc(this: MathData) {
        this.avg // ok
        this.c // ok
        this.diam // ok
    }
}
```

Please, be aware that TypeScript does not track mutations.Hence, in order to get `c` or `avg` or `diam` you need to explicitly type `this` parameter.
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQFkEQBYBEsKoDewqZqSAXKmAK4C2ARrANynkIBuA5tXU63ZkAJiAT0%20DZjDYBfYMCQB7MAGcIqRrRAAbYbFQBeVAAoEkgTAA0mi9ICUlTDnwRChgHymS5CtWfYAHSqAI4wEGaoAFSohADUmtGa9lZCsTzUkQmM9qgA9KgATKm%20ouL%20WEEIjKomjKgAtLEpwLL2Coo6CKqqGACeAMJdPcRpymoQMLRIEEowZnawNoyLMLk%20vuQA8owAVlAzgd2qINxgJjggqsvaerBmy-b2bGnyvkgIOkgX2FcVLgR1mlfJdVEcePkCkoANbA8igwJISGoGFwsgIsr0ZGo3zyeTAIA)